# Java memory benchmark

Tags: java, memory, data-structures, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm currently developing own pet project in Java which consist of custom data structures.
To measure performance I chose Google Caliper framework, but to measure memory usage of data  structure I should each time measure it using VisuamVm (dump heap and wait for calculation of object retained size), to get valid results. I want to make some kind of "memory benchmark" tests.

So, the question is:

Is there any Java framework similar to [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) or [JunitBenchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) that allows to make tests to measure memory consumption of my data structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool is appropriate for you. [Open JDK - Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)

[Sample examining HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21212806/861114)

```
$ java -jar jol-cli/target/jol-internals.jar java.util.HashMap
  Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
  Using compressed references with 3-bit shift.
  Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
  Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
  Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

  java.util.HashMap object internals:
   OFFSET  SIZE       TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
    0     4            (object header)                01 00 00 00 (00000001 00000000    00000000 00000000)
    4     4            (object header)                00 00 00 00 (00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000)
    8     4            (object header)                0f 0f 3e e0 (00001111 00001111 00111110 11100000)
   12     4        Set AbstractMap.keySet             null
   16     4 Collection AbstractMap.values             null
   20     4        int HashMap.size                   0
   24     4        int HashMap.threshold              16
   28     4      float HashMap.loadFactor             0.75
   32     4        int HashMap.modCount               0
   36     4        int HashMap.hashSeed               0
   40     4    Entry[] HashMap.table                  []
   44     4        Set HashMap.entrySet               null
   Instance size: 48 bytes (estimated, add this JAR via -javaagent: to get accurate result)
   Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know of a library for that, there are better approaches than taking a heap dump to mesaure memory use: You can ask the JVM to perform a garbace collection with `System.gc()`, and then query heap usage with `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` .

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I known this isn't best way to measure object accurate size.

Comment: Why not? And do you want to measure object size, or find the heap memory usage contribution of an entire object graph? That's not the same ...

Comment: I need retained size of my object. When I analyzed heap using VisuamVm i find a lot of objects, that was created not from my tests program (I run it from IntelliJ) and as I understood there is a possibility to get invalid results using Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory().

Answer (score 0):

Memory benchmark contains two points: *throughput* and *fragment*. Here I think what you want to do is choose what's the better data structure for these environment. For this point, I think you also need these two points to measure.

Here you can use **OQL**(Object query language) to query this datastructure usage. You can use **hprof** and **MAT** to analysis your system's heap context.

To solve your the question that making tests to measure the memory consumption, I suggest these steps:

1. Create a productive environment
2. Run the program
3. In the important point, you can dump your heap [Use JMX to make HPROF heap dumps right before and after a full GC](https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/978336)
4. Use **MAT**, **VisualVM** to analysis the hprof

Comment: Thanks! Can you please recommend some articles about throughput and fragment in context of memory in Java ? I've never heard about this terms before.